# My tic tac toe game is getting a TypeError I don't understand

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me where the errors are in this? I have been going around in circles for over a week trying to figure it out. I am getting the error 
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"
for the line of code in the playerXturn() function that is trying to put an "X" where the player chooses the indices.

```
def main():
    gameBoard = [[" ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " "]]

    printBoard(gameBoard)

    playerXturn(gameBoard)

    while boardFull(gameBoard) is False:

        if diagonalWin(gameBoard) is False and rowWin(gameBoard) is False:
            playerOturn(gameBoard)
            if diagonalWin(gameBoard) is False and rowWin(gameBoard) is False:
                playerXturn(gameBoard)
            else:
                print("Player X wins!")
        else:
            print("Player O wins!")

        printBoard(gameBoard)


def printBoard(gameBoard):
    print("---------")
    print(gameBoard[0][0], "|", gameBoard[0][1], "|", gameBoard[0][2])
    print("---------")
    print(gameBoard[1][0], "|", gameBoard[1][1], "|", gameBoard[1][2])
    print("---------")
    print(gameBoard[2][0], "|", gameBoard[2][1], "|", gameBoard[2][2])
    print("---------")


def playerXturn(gameBoard):
    playerXrowChoice = input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
    playerXrow = [eval(x) for x in playerXrowChoice]
    playerXcolumnChoice = input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
    playerXcolumn = [eval(x) for x in playerXcolumnChoice]

    if gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "X" and gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "O":
        gameBoard[playerXrow, playerXcolumn] = "X"
    else:
        print("This spot is already taken.")

    return gameBoard


def playerOturn(gameBoard):
    playerOrowChoice = input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
    playerOrow = [eval(x) for x in playerOrowChoice]
    playerOcolumnChoice = input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
    playerOcolumn = [eval(x) for x in playerOcolumnChoice]

    if gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "X" and gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "O":
        gameBoard[playerOrow, playerOcolumn] = "O"
    else:
        print("This spot is already taken.")

    return gameBoard

#check for empty spaces on the board
def boardFull(gameBoard):
    for i in range(len(gameBoard)):
        for j in range(len(gameBoard[i])):
            if j != " ":
                return True
            else:
                return False


#check for diagonal match
def diagonalWin(b):
    while b[1][1] != " ":
        if b[1][1] == b[0][0] == b[2][2] or b[1][1] == b[0][2] == b[2][0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

#check for 3 in a row
def rowWin(b):
    for row in range(0, 3):
        if b[row][0] == b[row][1] == b[row][2] == 'X':
            return True
        else:
            return False

main()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback of your error.

Comment: After removing playerXturn() from before the while loop, now I can not get the while loop to stop

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
gameBoard[playerXrow, playerXcolumn] = "X"
```

I think you meant:

```
gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] = "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to python so I don't know what eval() does, but I figured out where is the error.

```
def playerXturn(gameBoard):
playerXrowChoice= input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
playerXrow = [eval(x) for x in playerXrowChoice]
playerXcolumnChoice= input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
playerXcolumn = [eval(x) for x in playerXcolumnChoice]

if gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "X" and gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "O":
    gameBoard[playerXrow, playerXcolumn] = "X"
else:
    print("This spot is already taken.")

return gameBoard
```

Here on line:

```
gameBoard[playerOrow, playerOcolumn] = "X"
```

here you need to target a specific cell of like this: gameBoard[row][column] in this case:

```
gameBoard[playerOrow][playerOcolumn] = "X"
```

and I tried to run the code after this change and I got another error, but I solved it.

As I said I don't know what lines:

```
playerXcolumn = [eval(x) for x in playerXcolumnChoice]
playerXcolumn = [eval(x) for x in playerXcolumnChoice]
```

do so I removed them and where you ask for user input:

```
playerXrowChoice= input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
playerXcolumnChoice= input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
```

You need to convert input from string to int, so you can target the correct cell of the gameBoard.

Comment: Thank you. I am now unable to get the while loop to stop. The If statements are not catching. I feel like this is a train wreck.

Comment: Yea, I tried to run it again and I didn't get a matrix  with x in it. I'm trying to see whats the problem.

Comment: def playerXturn(gameBoard):
    playerXrow = int(input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: "))
    playerXcolumn = int(input("Enter a column (0, 1, or 2) for player X: "))

    if gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "X" and gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] != "O":
        gameBoard[playerXrow][playerXcolumn] = "X"
    else:
        print("This spot is already taken.")

    return gameBoard

Comment: Sorry - I am new to this forum. I pasted the resolved code for the player turn. Now that part will work.

Comment: Also you don't have to check if the current spot is not X or O, you can just check if it's == " " empty

Comment: I can solve this for you if you want and paste the code here, but it will be a lot of changes that I won't explain.